# Xcode does not find framework after closing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

i have a swift XCode project and i want to import Chartboost framework inside it. it works fine when i import the framework but when i close XCode and re-open, it gives error and says that could not find the files although the files are right there. here is the error :

```
'Chartboost/Chartboost.h' file not found
Failed to import bridging header '/..../project-Bridging-Header.h'
```

there are other frameworks inside the project but they do not give any error. i have to delete the framework and then copy it every time i close XCode. how do i fix this ?

Comment: Hey try link below it might be helpful.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496055/getting-file-not-found-in-bridging-header-when-importing-objective-c-framework

Comment: @KababChi Did you fix your issue ?

Comment: @Coder1000 Nope ! Still searching for answers !

Comment: @KababChi You should say it then! If not, people will assume you fixed your issue and forgot to accept an answer !

Comment: @Coder1000 Yupp! will tell when i find the answer. BTW this question was asked yesterday. surely one will understand this is not solved !

Comment: @KababChi No, as I said: if you don't comment on an answer that was given, people will assume you have lost interest in your own question and solved your case without even upvoting or accepting the answer of the person who spent some time to try to help you. It happens more frequently than you could imagine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Please check the  Framework Search Path in Target .If this frame work exists in folder name with space for example "Silly Things" .Then it will take two lines.So you have to give the name "Silly\ Things" in Framework Search Path.

2.If you are removing and adding again and again.Then it is just appending again and again in framework path.

So if you are closing and then opening it is not finding with suggested path and might be ending with this error.