# error: failed to import bridging header when trying to Archive

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to Archive my project but I can't because this error:

```
/Users/username/Developer/clickbalance/cb-ventas/CB Ventas/CB Ventas/Header.h:12:9: error: 'StarIO_Extension/StarIoExt.h' file not found

#import <StarIO_Extension/StarIoExt.h>
    ^
<unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header '/Users/username/Developer/clickbalance/cb-ventas/CB Ventas/CB Ventas/Header.h'

** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

I tried everything like the other questions says about a similiar error like this question: [Getting "file not found" in Bridging Header when importing Objective-C frameworks into Swift project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496055/getting-file-not-found-in-bridging-header-when-importing-objective-c-framework)

But nothing work.

Here is the location of the framework and the header file:

[image: location]

I linked the `.frameworks` files in the `Link Binary With Libraries` too.

This is my header file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#ifndef StarIO_Extension_Bridging_Header_h
#define StarIO_Extension_Bridging_Header_h

#import <StarIO_Extension/StarIoExt.h>
#import <StarIO_Extension/StarIoExtManager.h>

#endif /* StarIO_Extension_Bridging_Header_h */
```

The `Objective-C Bridging Header` I set to `${PROJECT_DIR}/CB Ventas/Header.h` and is set at the Target level, and NOT the Project level

I'm using Cocoapods too.

How can I solve that problem to archive the project?

Comment: @pableiors Hello Have you found solution for this.I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the framework checkbox checked for the target you are trying to archive in the Utilities pane -> Target Membership:

[image: Target Membership]