# Xcode build errors when running Cordova run command

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am using the latest version of Cordova 6.4.0 to build an application on the iPhone (using Xcode obviously).

When I run the cordova run command to build the app I get the following errors in the terminal.

```
<unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header 
'/Users/development/abc/mobapp/platforms/ios/abchq/Bridging-Header.h

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
     CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.xwift.compiler
     CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/development/abc/mobapp/platforms/ios/QuickPost/NetworkTableViewController.swift
     CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/development/abc/mobapp/platforms/ios/QuickPost/ShareViewController.swift

(3 failures)

Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args:- xcconfig...... (a lot more info)
```

Can anyone suggest what could the cause of all of this - when I run this on the same machine for the Android it runs fine?? Any ideas?

My machine information is as follows:

```
Cordova CLI : 6.4.0
ios-deploy version : 1.9.1
ios-sim version: 5.0.13
OS : macOS Sierra
Node version : v7.1.0
Xcode version : Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002
```

Answer (score 1):

The "Objective-C Bridging Header" setting (aka SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER) must be set at the Target level, and NOT the Project level. Be sure to delete the setting value at the Project level. This should resolve the issue.

Check out this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496055/getting-file-not-found-in-bridging-header-when-importing-objective-c-framework) for more info on this.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I set it at the Target level instead of Project level?

Comment: Do I have to make changes to the plugin.xml file, which is using that bridging header file?

Comment: @MuhammadMehdiRaza check it out here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496055/getting-file-not-found-in-bridging-header-when-importing-objective-c-framework