# filename.h file not found error in Xcode 8 while creating framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode8

I'm trying to create a framework using this steps https://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios

I've imported the framework file into project and I can able to create object for the framework file and access the methods. But when I build the project it is telling that file is not found.

Comment: Go to **Project -> Target -> Build Phase -> Headers**. Make sure the.h file you want to import is added into **public** section.

Comment: check once build phases your .h is added or not

Comment: Make sure the file is added to your target

Comment: Try deleting framework's reference from project navigator and again add them.

Comment: @Wolverine yes its there.  I can able to access that class methods in my viewcontroller while doing that its not showing any errors.  When I try to build its showing .h file not found

Comment: ok. Go to **your project in which you are using framework**. Go to  **That Project -> Target -> General -> Linked Framework and Libraries** and make sure your framework added in that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure your .h file is in public section of **'Copy Headers'** as shown in snap shot
[image]

- Just add you **framework's bundle** to **embedded libraries** as [image]

Comment: Just add "RWUIControls.bundle" to embedded libraries. This will resolve your issue.

Comment: Do we need to add in framework's target or project's target.  In framework's target I can't able to see that option

Comment: @SivagamiSundari In your project's target.