# "FileName.h" not found in Xcode 8.2 , Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sdk

I am preparing a SDK in objective framework, i added a file and imported a "FileName.h" but it giving me an error of **file not found**.
Any suggestion will be greatful

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41039967/filename-h-file-not-found-error-in-xcode-8-while-creating-framework

Comment: Thanks @ Anbu.Karthik, i have already done all this but no sucess..

Comment: clean and run once

Answer (score 0):

Are you able import the framework in your project. If **YES**, check

> Framework Search Paths in Build settings.

**Example:** $(PROJECT_DIR)/xxxxxxxx/GoogleSignIn\

Add your **framework** inside

> Embedded Binaries