# Xcode can't find .h file "ABC.h file not found"

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

React-native project was working fine. I ran `npm install react-native-animatable --save` and then the build failed when running `react-native run-ios` from console. failed with `exit code 65`. so I deleted ios/build folder.

opened project in Xcode, cleaned project, cleaned build folder, and rebuilt project.

build fails because "SplashScreen.h" file was not found in AppDelegate.m file

I've tried pretty much every answer from here: [.h file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198905/h-file-not-found)

~ cleaning project and build folder

~ deleting and re-adding ABC.m file to Build Phases -> Compile sources (even though the .m file wasn't there)

~ Checked both SplashScreen.h & SplashScreen.m for cyclic imports, negative

~ Changed location setting of SplashScreen.h and the entire project from "Relative to Group" to "Relative to Project"

~ Quitting/Retarting metro bundler and Xcode

~ restarting computer

~ opening SplashScreen.m and unchecked/checked the target membership button in the right panel (Utilities)

~ Operating in the Legacy Build

~ re-ran `react-native link react-native-splash-screen`

I don't know why all of a sudden this splash screen file can't be found. everything was fine, I expect my app to build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Something with the SplashScreen library must have changed. Even though I never edited anything, the AppDelegate.m file was looking for `#import SplashScreen.h`, and `SplashScreen.h` somehow was changed to `RNSplashScreen.h`. I had top change that as well as `[SplashScreen show]` -> `[RNSplashScreen show]`